# Including categorical colours with \newcommand in PdfLatex

Tags: macros, lists, text, html

I wish to have a list of predefined HTML colour codes and convert them into a numbered reusable variable which can then be referenced later. This is useful when having a set number of variables or categories you wish to colour inline without having to remember the definition name, or create large amounts of definitions and type out `\textcolour{colname}{text}` everytime.

Definition:

```
cols = ['#222','#ffc','#123']
```

Usage:

```
\c1 {text in firstcolour} and then \c2{text in secondcolour}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a counter in conjunction with a newcommand macro to future-generate newcommands that can colour text. A simple example is given below:

```
%define colours pre document 

\newcounter{cnt}
\newcommand{\cdef}[1]{%
 \stepcounter{cnt}%
\xglobal \definecolor{#1}{HTML}{#1}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname c\Roman{cnt}\endcsname{\textcolor{#1}}%
}


%start the main body
\begin{document}



% Define list of colours to run here, reference with \cI \cII \cIII etc... 
\cdef{00CCFF}
\cdef{99CC99}


%write away within the document
\cI {test c1} and then \cII{test c2}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can build a list referenced to by numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\colorlist}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_colorlist_list_seq { ##1 }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\usecolor}{mm}
 {
  \textcolor[HTML]{ \seq_item:Nn \g_colorlist_list_seq { #1 } } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_colorlist_list_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff

\colorlist{828282,FF0000,00FF00}

\begin{document}

\usecolor{1}{text in first color}

\usecolor{2}{text in second color}

\usecolor{3}{text in third color}

\end{document}
```

Note that `xcolor` requires HTML colors to be given as a string of *six* hexadecimal digits, uppercase or lowercase.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You ask for a command `\c`.
`\c` is already defined by the LaTeX 2e-kernel to deliver a letter with a cedilla.
Therefore in the examples below a command `\ColorNumber` is defined instead.

---

Here comes a variation of what you provided as your own answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

% define colours pre document 

\newcommand\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal{0}%
\newcommand\cdef[1]{%
 \@bsphack
 \begingroup
 \@tempcnta=\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal\relax
 \advance\@tempcnta by 1\relax
 \xdef\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal{\number\@tempcnta}%
 \endgroup
 \xglobal\definecolor{%
   MYNAMESPACEDefinedColor\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal%
 }{HTML}{#1}%
 \@esphack
}

\newcommand\ColorNumber[1]{\textcolor{MYNAMESPACEDefinedColor#1}}%

\makeatother

%start the main body
\begin{document}

\cdef{00CCFF}
\cdef{99CC99}

%write away within the document
\ColorNumber{1}{test c1} and then \ColorNumber{2}{test c2}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here comes another variation of what you provided as your own answer, here `\ColorNumber`'s first argument is delimited by a curly brace via `#1#`-notation in the parameter-text—this is closer to the notation you asked for in your question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

% define colours pre document 

\newcommand\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal{0}%
\newcommand\cdef[1]{%
 \@bsphack
 \begingroup
 \@tempcnta=\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal\relax
 \advance\@tempcnta by 1\relax
 \xdef\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal{\number\@tempcnta}%
 \endgroup
 \xglobal\definecolor{%
   MYNAMESPACEDefinedColor\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal%
 }{HTML}{#1}%
 \@esphack
}

\newcommand\ColorNumber{}%
\def\ColorNumber#1#{\textcolor{MYNAMESPACEDefinedColor#1}}%

\makeatother

%start the main body
\begin{document}

\cdef{00CCFF}
\cdef{99CC99}

%write away within the document
\ColorNumber1{test c1} and then \ColorNumber2{test c2}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here comes yet another variation where spaces trailing the number get removed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,\UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@RemoveTrailingSpaces{<argument>} removes trailing spaces from <argument>.
%% !!!! <argument> must not contain the token \UD@seldom !!!!
%%.............................................................................
\begingroup
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTrailingSpaces[1]{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\UD@RemoveTrailingSpaces[1]{%
    \romannumeral0%
    \UD@trimtrailspaceloop.##1\UD@seldom#1\UD@seldom\UD@seldom#1{.##1}%
  }%
  \newcommand\UD@trimtrailspaceloop{}%
  \long\def\UD@trimtrailspaceloop##1#1\UD@seldom##2\UD@seldom#1##3{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##2}{%
      \UD@firstoftwo{ }##3%
    }{%
      \UD@trimtrailspaceloop##1\UD@seldom#1\UD@seldom\UD@seldom#1{##1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\UD@RemoveTrailingSpaces{ }%

% define colours pre document 

\newcommand\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal{0}%
\newcommand\cdef[1]{%
 \@bsphack
 \begingroup
 \@tempcnta=\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal\relax
 \advance\@tempcnta by 1\relax
 \xdef\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal{\number\@tempcnta}%
 \endgroup
 \xglobal\definecolor{%
   MYNAMESPACEDefinedColor\MYNAMESPACEDefinedColorTotal%
 }{HTML}{#1}%
 \@esphack
}

\newcommand\ColorNumber{}%
\def\ColorNumber#1#{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@ColorNumber
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTrailingSpaces{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand*\@ColorNumber[1]{%
  \textcolor{MYNAMESPACEDefinedColor#1}%
}%

\makeatother

%start the main body
\begin{document}

\cdef{00CCFF}
\cdef{99CC99}

%write away within the document
\ColorNumber1{test c1} and then \ColorNumber2{test c2}

\ColorNumber 1 {test c1} and then \ColorNumber 2 {test c2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If the list of colors is small, you could use something like `\UD@PassKthArg` for extracting the K-th element of that list and passing it on to `\textcolor`—this way you can call `\textcolor` even without the need of defining the color via `\definecolor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}%

\makeatletter
%% Code for \UD@PassKthArg
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, UD@Exchange, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, 
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull, UD@CheckWhetherBlank
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only spaces):
%%..............................................................................
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}.}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Put K-th inner undelimited argument behind sequence of tokens:
%%
%% \UD@PassKthArg{<tokens>}{<ErrorTokens>}{<integer K>}{<list of undelimited args>} 
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver <ErrorTokens>.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does place that K-th argument with one level of braces removed behind <tokens>.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \UD@PassKthArg{ELEMENT-}{ERROR}{0}{ABCDE} yields: ERROR
%%
%%   \UD@PassKthArg{ELEMENT-}{ERROR}{3}{ABCDE} yields:  ELEMENT-C
%%
%%   \UD@PassKthArg{ELEMENT-}{ERROR}{3}{AB{CD}E} yields:  ELEMENT-CD
%%
%%   \UD@PassKthArg{ELEMENT-}{ERROR}{4}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: ELEMENT-004
%%
%%   \UD@PassKthArg{ELEMENT-}{ERROR}{6}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: ERROR
%% 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@PassKthArg[3]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  % #1: <Tokens>
  % #2: <ErrorTokens>
  % #3: <integer number K>
  \expandafter\UD@PassKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#3 000}{#1}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@PassKthArgCheck[4]{%
  % #1 - <K letters m>
  % #2 - <Tokens>
  % #3 - <ErrorTokens>
  % #4 - <list>
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{ #3}{%
    \expandafter\UD@PassKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#4}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@PassKthArgLoop[4]{%
  % #1 - <letters m in an amount that corresponds to the number
  %       of arguments trailing the to-be-kept argument>
  % #2 - <list>
  % #3 - <Tokens>
  % #4 - <ErrorTokens>
  \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#2}{ #4}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{%
      \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#2\UD@SelDOm}{#3}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}%
      {\expandafter\UD@PassKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}}%
      {#3}{#4}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange#1{ #2}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}{#2}}%
}%
%% End of code for \UD@PassKthArg

\newcommand\ColorNumber[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\Mycolorlist}{\UD@PassKthArg{\textcolor}{%
    \GenericError{%
      \@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\space\space\space
    }{%
       Error with command \string\ColorNumber: \string\Mycolorlist\space does not have a%
       \MessageBreak color-specification-element #1%
    }{Color will not be changed.}{Specify the number of an element which is in the list.}%
  }{#1}}%
}%
\makeatother

\definecolor{myweirdcolor}{HTML}{800080}% PURPLE

% List of color-specifications.
% Each specification must be nested in braces.
% You are not bound to the HTML-Hex-Code-model.

\newcommand\Mycolorlist{%
  {[HTML]{00CCFF}}% CYAN
  {[HTML]{C0C0C0}}% SILVER
  {[HTML]{808080}}% GRAY
  {[HTML]{000000}}% BLACK
  {[rgb]{1,0,0}}  % RED
  {[HTML]{800000}}% MAROON
  {[HTML]{FFFF00}}% YELLOW
  {[HTML]{808000}}% OLIVE
  {[HTML]{00FF00}}% LIME
  {[HTML]{008000}}% GREEN
  {[HTML]{00FFFF}}% AQUA
  {[HTML]{008080}}% TEAL
  {[HTML]{0000FF}}% BLUE
  {[HTML]{000080}}% NAVY
  {[HTML]{FF00FF}}% FUCHSIA
  {{myweirdcolor}}% PURPLE
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\ColorNumber{1}{test C1 - CYAN}\\
\ColorNumber{2}{test C2 - SILVER}\\
\ColorNumber{3}{test C3 - GRAY}\\
\ColorNumber{4}{test C4 - BLACK}\\
\ColorNumber{5}{test C5 - RED}\\
\ColorNumber{6}{test C6 - MAROON}\\
\ColorNumber{7}{test C7 - YELLOW}\\
\ColorNumber{8}{test C8 - OLIVE}\\
\ColorNumber{9}{test C9 - LIME}\\
\ColorNumber{10}{test C10 - GREEN}\\
\ColorNumber{11}{test C11 - AQUA}\\
\ColorNumber{12}{test C12 - TEAL}\\
\ColorNumber{13}{test C13 - BLUE}\\
\ColorNumber{14}{test C14 - NAVY}\\
\ColorNumber{15}{test C15 - FUCHSIA}\\
\ColorNumber{16}{test C16 - PURPLE}\\
%\ColorNumber{17}{test C17 - ERROR}\\
%\ColorNumber{0}{test C0 - ERROR}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Combining the approach from above, where trailing spaces behind the number get removed, with the approach where 
`\UD@PassKthArg` is used for for extracting the K-th element yields:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}%

\makeatletter
%% Code for \UD@PassKthArg
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, UD@Exchange, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, 
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull, UD@CheckWhetherBlank
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only spaces):
%%..............................................................................
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}.}%
}%
%%==============================================================================
%% Put K-th inner undelimited argument behind sequence of tokens:
%%
%% \UD@PassKthArg{<tokens>}{<ErrorTokens>}{<integer K>}{<list of undelimited args>} 
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver <ErrorTokens>.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does place that K-th argument with one level of braces removed behind <tokens>.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \UD@PassKthArg{ELEMENT-}{ERROR}{0}{ABCDE} yields: ERROR
%%
%%   \UD@PassKthArg{ELEMENT-}{ERROR}{3}{ABCDE} yields:  ELEMENT-C
%%
%%   \UD@PassKthArg{ELEMENT-}{ERROR}{3}{AB{CD}E} yields:  ELEMENT-CD
%%
%%   \UD@PassKthArg{ELEMENT-}{ERROR}{4}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: ELEMENT-004
%%
%%   \UD@PassKthArg{ELEMENT-}{ERROR}{6}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: ERROR
%% 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@PassKthArg[3]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  % #1: <Tokens>
  % #2: <ErrorTokens>
  % #3: <integer number K>
  \expandafter\UD@PassKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#3 000}{#1}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@PassKthArgCheck[4]{%
  % #1 - <K letters m>
  % #2 - <Tokens>
  % #3 - <ErrorTokens>
  % #4 - <list>
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{ #3}{%
    \expandafter\UD@PassKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#4}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@PassKthArgLoop[4]{%
  % #1 - <letters m in an amount that corresponds to the number
  %       of arguments trailing the to-be-kept argument>
  % #2 - <list>
  % #3 - <Tokens>
  % #4 - <ErrorTokens>
  \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#2}{ #4}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{%
      \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#2\UD@SelDOm}{#3}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}%
      {\expandafter\UD@PassKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}}%
      {#3}{#4}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange#1{ #2}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}{#2}}%
}%
%% End of code for \UD@PassKthArg
%%==============================================================================
%% \UD@RemoveTrailingSpaces{<argument>} removes trailing spaces from <argument>.
%% !!!! <argument> must not contain the token \UD@seldom !!!!
%%==============================================================================
\begingroup
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTrailingSpaces[1]{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\UD@RemoveTrailingSpaces[1]{%
    \romannumeral0%
    \UD@trimtrailspaceloop.##1\UD@seldom#1\UD@seldom\UD@seldom#1{.##1}%
  }%
  \newcommand\UD@trimtrailspaceloop{}%
  \long\def\UD@trimtrailspaceloop##1#1\UD@seldom##2\UD@seldom#1##3{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##2}{%
      \UD@firstoftwo{ }##3%
    }{%
      \UD@trimtrailspaceloop##1\UD@seldom#1\UD@seldom\UD@seldom#1{##1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\UD@RemoveTrailingSpaces{ }%
%% End of code for \UD@RemoveTrailingSpaces

\newcommand\ColorNumber{}%
\def\ColorNumber#1#{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@ColorNumber
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTrailingSpaces{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\@ColorNumber[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\Mycolorlist}{\UD@PassKthArg{\textcolor}{%
    \GenericError{%
      \@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\space\space\space
    }{%
       Error with command \string\ColorNumber: \string\Mycolorlist\space does not have a%
       \MessageBreak color-specification-element #1%
    }{Color will not be changed.}{Specify the number of an element which is in the list.}%
  }{#1}}%
}%
\makeatother

\definecolor{myweirdcolor}{HTML}{800080}% PURPLE

% List of color-specifications.
% Each specification must be nested in braces.
% You are not bound to the HTML-Hex-Code-model.

\newcommand\Mycolorlist{%
  {[HTML]{00CCFF}}% CYAN
  {[HTML]{C0C0C0}}% SILVER
  {[HTML]{808080}}% GRAY
  {[HTML]{000000}}% BLACK
  {[rgb]{1,0,0}}  % RED
  {[HTML]{800000}}% MAROON
  {[HTML]{FFFF00}}% YELLOW
  {[HTML]{808000}}% OLIVE
  {[HTML]{00FF00}}% LIME
  {[HTML]{008000}}% GREEN
  {[HTML]{00FFFF}}% AQUA
  {[HTML]{008080}}% TEAL
  {[HTML]{0000FF}}% BLUE
  {[HTML]{000080}}% NAVY
  {[HTML]{FF00FF}}% FUCHSIA
  {{myweirdcolor}}% PURPLE
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\ColorNumber1{test C1 - CYAN}\\
\ColorNumber2{test C2 - SILVER}\\
\ColorNumber3{test C3 - GRAY}\\
\ColorNumber4{test C4 - BLACK}\\
\ColorNumber5{test C5 - RED}\\
\ColorNumber6{test C6 - MAROON}\\
\ColorNumber7{test C7 - YELLOW}\\
\ColorNumber8{test C8 - OLIVE}\\
\ColorNumber9{test C9 - LIME}\\
\ColorNumber10{test C10 - GREEN}\\
\ColorNumber11{test C11 - AQUA}\\
\ColorNumber12{test C12 - TEAL}\\
\ColorNumber13{test C13 - BLUE}\\
\ColorNumber14{test C14 - NAVY}\\
\ColorNumber15{test C15 - FUCHSIA}\\
\ColorNumber16{test C16 - PURPLE}\\
%\ColorNumber17{test C17 - ERROR}\\
%\ColorNumber0{test C0 - ERROR}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the xColors package for that:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}

%Color palette that looks great
\definecolor{xRed}{HTML}{B51E0E}    %[0.71 0.12 0.06]
\definecolor{xGreen}{HTML}{6DB565}  %[0.23 0.51 0.20]
\definecolor{xBlue}{HTML}{074E82}   %[0.03 0.31 0.51]
\definecolor{xBrown}{HTML}{9C5C19}  %[0.61 0.36 0.10]
\definecolor{xYellow}{HTML}{F7B538} %[0.97 0.71 0.22]
\definecolor{xOrange}{HTML}{EC6D00} %[0.93 0.43 0.00]
\definecolor{xCyan}{HTML}{0094AC}   %[0.00 0.58 0.68]
\definecolor{xPurple}{HTML}{8711A1} %[0.53 0.07 0.64]
\definecolor{xPink}{HTML}{D30580}   %[0.83 0.02 0.51]
```

And then use like this:

```
\textcolor{xCyan}{cyan}
```

Oh, and btw, when coloring text it usually looks better in bold:

```
\textcolor{xCyan}{\textbf{cyan}}
```

Comment: For that you have to define each colour with a code separately. You'll see that in my answer I simply use \cI ,  \cII  \cIII to summon the colours inline. It is much less writing and easier to edit when you decide to change the order of the colours.